# How can i can change the value of a variable with if/else to return certain div in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm triying to change a div value after an API consult and if/else statement in react. Per example, in angular with scope i can have some value and change it after an if/else statement, something like:

```
$scope.text = ""

if(something){
 $scope.text = "Hello"
}
else {
$scope.text = "Goodbye"
}
```

I need to do the same in react. Here's part of my code so far:

```
function QuantityBtn() {
  const theIds = [{'id': 1, 'value': "one"}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'two'}]
  let special = null

  const findData = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: "/api/",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },      
  };
  
  axios(findData)     
  .then(function(data) {
    const returnedInfo = data.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < theIds.length; i++){
     for(var j = 0; j = returnedInfo.length; j++){
      if(theIds[i].id == returnedInfo[j].id){
         return special = true
      }
      else{
         return special = false
      }
    }
  }
})   
.catch(err => console.error(err))

  return (
    <div
      className="miTest"
    >{special}</div>
  )
}
```

So, as you can see what i'm triying to do is:

1. Consult the API
2. With the data response (`const returnedInfo`) i run over the array (`const theIds`) and the response itself and make a validation: if exist an id of the array inside of the response, the value on the returned div have to change to true, and if not (else statement), the value have to change to false;

My problem it's simple: the variable value is not changing. Can you tell me, please, if there's something else to do to change it? I've checked response of the api and run some tests, and there's one of the ids of the array that is equal to the id in the response. So the validation it's fine. I just need to find out how to change the variable `let special`

As i'd said before, i'm using react and i'm barely new.

**EDIT**

I've just discovered on the console that the value is changing, the problem it's on the front, the return with the div is not catching and printing the value... Do you know why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

remove the return before the true and false

```
      if(theIds[i].id == returnedInfo[j].id){
         special = true
      }
      else{
         special = false
      }
```

Comment: I've already remove it, but still not working

Comment: On the console is working, my problem it's inside of the return, i think is not catching the parameter